# How to filter timestamps within a custom interval starting at the index on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to filter rows within 5 minutes of the timestamp following each "True" condition, including the timestamp of the "True" condition. I've come up with a solution using a for loop but it can be rather slow with a large amount of data so I'm curious if there's a faster solution.

```py
time,cond
2019-08-03 21:44:15.924000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 21:45:15.924000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:21:15.937000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:26:15.937000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:33:15.946000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:42:15.939000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:44:15.948000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:45:15.955000+00:00,True
2019-08-03 22:46:15.949000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:01:15.932000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:08:15.933000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:17:15.957000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:45:15.952000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:46:15.943000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:52:15.943000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:54:15.952000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:05:15.929000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:29:15.944000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:45:15.956000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:46:15.939000+00:00,True
2019-08-04 00:47:15.955000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 01:00:15.956000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 01:02:15.943000+00:00,False
```

```py
for i in x[x.cond].index.to_list():
    x.loc[(x.time >= x.iloc[i].time) & (x.time <= (x.iloc[i].time + pd.Timedelta('5min'))), 'cond'] = True
```

This is the expected output. The 'cond' column updated to true if it falls within 5 minutes of the timestamp of the original "True" condition timestamp. I've tried a few other solutions but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated.

```py
time,cond
2019-08-03 21:44:15.924000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 21:45:15.924000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:21:15.937000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:26:15.937000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:33:15.946000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:42:15.939000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:44:15.948000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 22:45:15.955000+00:00,True
2019-08-03 22:46:15.949000+00:00,True
2019-08-03 23:01:15.932000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:08:15.933000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:17:15.957000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:45:15.952000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:46:15.943000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:52:15.943000+00:00,False
2019-08-03 23:54:15.952000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:05:15.929000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:29:15.944000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:45:15.956000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 00:46:15.939000+00:00,True
2019-08-04 00:47:15.955000+00:00,True
2019-08-04 01:00:15.956000+00:00,False
2019-08-04 01:02:15.943000+00:00,False
```

Comment: May be numpy striding tricks ( creating an emulated 5*2-columns strided-view onto the original array ) will help with numpy-smart vectorised processing w/o memory-allocations for interim data and using just all strided-rows, which have True in the [:,2]-column?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, iterating over rows in Pandas is not very efficient. I'm suggesting this solution, which avoids iterating all rows and takes advantage of Pandas capabilities. I think it is quite explicit and you wont have problems to understand/improve it, you may be able to avoid the short loop I left. I hope this helps as a starting point.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
mins = 5
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', skiprows=1, header=None, names=['datetime', 'stamp'])
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetime'])
print(data)
g = data.groupby('stamp')
for i, r in g.get_group(True).iterrows():
    data.loc[(data['datetime'] > r['datetime']) &  (data['datetime'] < r['datetime'] + datetime.timedelta(0, 60 * mins)), 'stamp'] = True 
print(data)
```